# If $G$ is an open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $T$ is a regular $n\times n$ matrix, then is $\{Tx\mid x\in G\}$ open?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, euclidean-geometry

> Let $G$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $T$ : $n \times n$ a regular matrix. Then $TG=\{ Tx | x \in G \}.$
>
> Does this proposition hold?
>
> $$G \text{ is an open set} \;\Longrightarrow\; TG \text{ is an open set}$$

**My attempt**

Let $G$ is open.
I want to prove $TG \subset TG^i$. Let $y \in TG$.

Then, I can write $y=Tx(x \in G)$
and $x=T^{-1}y \in G$.

Because $G$ is open, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x, r) \subset G$.

If I find $\delta>0$ such that $B(y, \delta) \subset TG$, I can prove $TG \subset TG^{i}$. But I couldn't find such $\delta$.

Does anyone know what $\delta$ is? or this proposition doesn't hold?

Comment: **Hint:** $x\mapsto T^{-1}x$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you. I could understand.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is a linear map so continuous (as the dimensions are finite), and being "regular", presumably means $T^{-1}$ also exists and is continuous (same reasons). So $T$ is a homeomorphism and in particular an open map. So your proposition holds.